# IE 9 - Object doesn't support property or method 'Format'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

need a little help here.

I decided to transfer some of my javascript function in one .js file. Those functions are working properly in other browser EXCEPT IE.

**NOTE:** 
Code below was store in a separate js file "**my_js.js**"

```
var dialogConfirmed = false;

function DialogConfirmation(obj, title, dialogText) {
    if (!dialogConfirmed) {
        $('body').append("<div id='dialog' title='" + title + "'>'" + dialogText + "'</div>");            
        $('#dialog').dialog
        ({
            height: 150,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            close: function(event, ui) { $('body').find('#dialog').remove(); },
            buttons:
            {
                'Yes': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    dialogConfirmed = true;
                    if (obj) obj.click();
                },
                'No': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return dialogConfirmed;
}
```

**Usage**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAlert" runat="server" Text="Alert" OnClientClick="return DialogConfirmation(this, 'Popup Header', 'Popup Body Message');" onclick="btnAlert_Click" />
```

When clicking the button it throws and error pointing to method "**Format**"

```
**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Format'**
```

But checking my code doesn't use '**Format**'. Any idea on the error? I'm using EI 9 on my workstation.

Comment: Where exactly does it throw the error? Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through?

Comment: You have two `onclicks`.

Comment: The error occur here.

     **$('body').append("<div id='dialog' title='" + title + "'>'" + dialogText + "'</div>");**

Comment: how are you including your scripts?

Comment: I include my script in the <head> tag of my Master Page. Inside ScriptManager seems not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote the same code and itz working fine. Please try it once. Thanks.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication8.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var dialogConfirmed = false;

        function DialogConfirmation(obj, title, dialogText) {
            if (!dialogConfirmed) {
                $('body').append("<div id='dialog' title='" + title + "'>'" + dialogText + "'</div>");
                $('#dialog').dialog
        ({
            height: 150,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            close: function (event, ui) { $('body').find('#dialog').remove(); },
            buttons:
            {
                'Yes': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    dialogConfirmed = true;
                    if (obj) obj.click();
                },
                'No': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
            }
            return dialogConfirmed;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAlert" runat="server" Text="Alert" OnClientClick="javascript:return DialogConfirmation(this, 'Popup Header', 'Popup Body Message');" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's working when you put it in a single page like what you did but my goal is to put some of my function in one .js file. Try creating a .js file then copy paste my code above then try to use it. It will produce error in **$('body').append("<div id='dialog' title='" + title + "'>'" + dialogText + "'</div>");
                $('#dialog').dialog**

Answer (score 0):

I have moved your Javascript code to separate file and everything is working fine in IE 9. Probably you have missed the adding of the jQuery-ui.js file in your code. Please see the working code below.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication8.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/my_js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAlert" runat="server" Text="Alert" OnClientClick="javascript:return DialogConfirmation(this, 'Popup Header', 'Popup Body Message');" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi skumar,

I have all the needed js and css to run jquery properly. Actually i already solved this problem an hour ago by clearing the cache of my browser(IE). :)